# How to display the stream data from beacon plugin as widget list

Tags: flutter, ibeacon

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter Beacon'),
        ),
        body: _beacons == null
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : ListView(
          children: ListTile.divideTiles(
              context: context,
              tiles: _beacons.map((beacon) {

                if(beacon.macAddress == "MAC_ADDRESS_FORMAT") {
                  print(beacon.macAddress);
                }
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(beacon.macAddress),
                  subtitle: new Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                              'Major: ${beacon.major}\nMinor: ${beacon.minor}',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0)),
                          flex: 1,
                          fit: FlexFit.tight),
                      Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                              'Accuracy: ${beacon.accuracy}m\nRSSI: ${beacon.rssi}',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0)),
                          flex: 2,
                          fit: FlexFit.tight)
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              })).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I need to display the stream data to a widget list. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish?  What does the code do now that is different from what you want?

Comment: Hi @davidgyoung! I want to display the ListTile for every beacon individually and update it according to their specific stream data. Currently it lists down all the data (not grouped). I tried with a simple if condition, I got the following error `I/flutter ( 6548): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4853 pos 12: 'child == _child': is not true.
I/flutter ( 6548): Another exception was thrown: Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.`